# serialized checkboxes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I would like to add 7 checkboxes (boolean values) to one of my Models.

Is there a way to make something like an array of bools in my db, instead of adding 7 different columns by hand?

Oh I'm using the pg database

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how often do you want those bool to be edited (in a form in ajax etc.).  You may be better off staying with individual columns.  Simply because the f.check_box :column_name versus f.object.column_name.each_pair ...  The similar situation in the controller when posting them back in.  Only good reason I can think of to add serialized 7 checkboxes in a hash and store them in one column is if your 7 checkboxes can be changed dynamically and such.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
CREATE TABLE array_test (
     bools bool[]
);
```

Not saying I recommend this approach.  Usually you are better with a mapping table or multiple columns for reasons of indexing, semantic clarity, and enforcing proper data integrity.  However, if you are weighing this I assume you know the hazards or else you will learn your lesson.  There are some rare cases where this makes sense however....